# Concat a URL in a string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, indexing

I am using HTML Agility Pack to take Image Source from a HTML Code.

Image link is

```
http://www.example.com/images/item001_ZM80.jpg
```

The value ZM80 changes for each image link I take (ZM80, ZM35) which denotes the Zoom value of the image. I want to remove that value "_ZMxx" where xx can be 01 to 99

I want to concat the link stored in a string variable to the following (Removed "_ZM80")

```
http://www.example.com/images/item001.jpg
```

Some cases the URL is

```
http://www.example.com/images/item001_ZM80_AL30.jpg
```

In that case also I want to remove just the _ZM80

I am able to get the Index value where ZM occurs in the variable.

```
int finalImage = imagestring.IndexOf("ZM");
```

Comment: sorry i cant understand your question .what u want.do u want to remove (_zm100) from url.

Comment: what programming language are you using ?

Comment: C# , added it in Tags

Comment: @user3270187 edited the question. Please check. Want to remove _ZMxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex.Replace` method for this.

**E.g.**

```
 string str = getUrl("http://www.example.com/images/item001_ZM80.jpg");
 string str1 = getUrl("http://www.example.com/images/item001_ZM80_AL30.jpg");

   public string getUrl(string url)
    {
        string result;

        result = Regex.Replace(url, "_ZM(.{2})", "");

        return result;
    }
```

If you are not sure after _ZM there can be less than 2 digit character then you can use following function to get URL:

```
    public string getUrl(string url)
    {
        string result;
        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(url);

        result = Regex.Replace(url, "_ZM(\\d{0,2})", "");

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the question. In some cases the URL will be _ZM80_AL30.jpg. even in that case I want to remove just the _ZM80

Comment: The updated code Removes the entire text after the occurrence of _ZM and adds .JPG twice.

Comment: I am running it in look. 

String str may contact _ZM80.jpg or may contain _ZM80_AL30.jpg which changes randmly for each link. 

So I dont think running it separately for two variables solves my problem

Comment: New code doesnt help. It shows no changes. Old code concatenated the entire text after _ZM  and gave extension twice.

Comment: I shared two example one with _ZM80 and one with _ZM80_AL30. I first checked that url match "_ZM(.*)_" pattern then replace it with "_". For _ZM80 it will be replaced with "" and extension append after that.

Comment: you can create function for it. function accept string url parameter and return replced url back.

Comment: It is fixed that after _ZM there will be only two digit ? means _ZM80 or _ZM90. it is possible that value can be _ZM100?

Comment: _ZM has only two digits. It will not have ZM100

Comment: Updated answer !! with assumption after _ZM always 2 digit.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = imagestring.IndexOf("ZM");
string number = imagestring.SubString(index + 2, imagestring.Length - (index + 6)); // index + 2 + ".jpg.length"
int imagenum = int.Parse(number);
string newImage = imagestring.Substring(0, index) + (imagenum + 1) + ".jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int percentIndex = imagestring.IndexOf("ZM");
if (percentIndex != -1)
{
     imagestring = imagestring.Remove(percentIndex, 4);
}
```